# Wrong Redirect for unauthorised action access in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my login page url: http://localhost/multi_shopping/PanelAdmin/Users/index.
After login i am redirected to the following url i.e. http://localhost/multi_shopping/PanelAdmin/categories/home. I have restricted user to not be able to access this url if he is not logged in, but if i hit http://localhost/multi_shopping/PanelAdmin/categories/home this url then i have been redirected to http://localhost/multi_shopping/users/login?redirect=%2FPanelAdmin%2FCategories%2Fhome, showing error message: Error: UsersController could not be found, but i am working in plugin PanelAdmin directory. I want user to redirect to login page if he tries to access category page without login. Please help to sort out my issue.

> Code snippet:
>
> AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize'=> 'Controller',
            'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                // fields used in login form
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],

           'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Categories',
                'action' => 'home'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
             'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'index',//,
            'prefix' => false

            //'home'

        ],

        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',

        ]);
```

> UsersController.php

```
public function login()
    {   
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            //debug($user); die;

            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());

            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

> CategoriesController.php

```
public function isAuthorized($user)

{   

    $action = $this->request->params['action'];

    //  registered users can add topics and view index

    if (in_array($action, ['home'])) {

    return true;

    }

    // All other actions require an id or users cannot do it

    if (empty($this->request->params['pass'][0])) {

        return false;

    }      

   return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

> routes.php Plugin File

```
Router::plugin(
    'PanelAdmin',
    ['path' => '/PanelAdmin'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    }
);
```

> routes.php  Application Route File

```
<?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @license       https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;

/**
 * The default class to use for all routes
 *
 * The following route classes are supplied with CakePHP and are appropriate
 * to set as the default:
 *
 * - Route
 * - InflectedRoute
 * - DashedRoute
 *
 * If no call is made to `Router::defaultRouteClass()`, the class used is
 * `Route` (`Cake\Routing\Route\Route`)
 *
 * Note that `Route` does not do any inflections on URLs which will result in
 * inconsistently cased URLs when used with `:plugin`, `:controller` and
 * `:action` markers.
 *
 */
Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    /**
     * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to a controller called 'Pages',
     * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
     * to use (in this case, src/Template/Pages/home.ctp)...
     */
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

     /**
     * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
     */
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

     /**
     * ...and connect Admin Panel URLs.
     */

    $routes->connect('/PanelAdmin', ['plugin' => 'PanelAdmin', 'controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index']);




    /**
     * Connect catchall routes for all controllers.
     *
     * Using the argument `DashedRoute`, the `fallbacks` method is a shortcut for
     *    `$routes->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index'], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);`
     *    `$routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', [], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);`
     *
     * Any route class can be used with this method, such as:
     * - DashedRoute
     * - InflectedRoute
     * - Route
     * - Or your own route class
     *
     * You can remove these routes once you've connected the
     * routes you want in your application.
     */
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */

Plugin::routes();
```

Comment: Just comment in / remove 'prefix' => false option within $this->loadComponent array.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka: Commented but the same issue.I have added routes.php file

Comment: will you post complete routes.php code..

Comment: posted code routes.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding appropriate prefix within your `routes.php` file, Add following just above `Plugin::routes();`

```
Router::prefix('PanelAdmin', function ($routes) {
 // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
 // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
 $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'ajax']);
 $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
 $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

And you can comment following line:

```
// $routes->connect('/PanelAdmin', ['plugin' => 'PanelAdmin', 'controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index']);
```

Comment: Getting this error: Error: PanelAdminController could not be found when trying to access any controller action. PanelAdmin should be plugin not controller i there anything wrong in routes.php file

Comment: the same issue http://localhost/multi_shopping/users/login?redirect=%2FPanelAdmin%2Fcategories%2Fhome redirected to this url when accessing ....../PanelAdmincategories/home

Comment: Is PanelAdmin placed within plugins directly?